# Holding down keys stops working after ~20 sec

Tags: keyboard

I am using an MSI wireless keyboard (model RF1430), and my keyboard works fine when I hold down keys for a short amount of time. However, when I hold down a key for longer than ~20 sec, it stops working until I press it again. This happens on all the programs I've tried, and it is very annoying when I play video games. Is this a hardware issue or can I fix it in settings?

Comment: Try a different Keyboard - that is what I would do.

Comment: If the problem persists on a different keyboard, it's a problem with your system. If it doesn't, the problem is with the keyboard. This is the way to diagnose this issue.